# gsub ASCII code characters from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using nokogiri to screen scrape some HTML.  In some occurrences, I am getting some weird characters back, I have tracked down the ASCII code for these characters with the following code:

```
  @parser.leads[0].phone_numbers[0].each_byte  do |c|
    puts "char=#{c}"
  end
```

The characters in question have an ASCII code of 194 and 160.

I want to somehow strip these characters out while parsing.

I have tried the following code but it does not work.

```
@parser.leads[0].phone_numbers[0].gsub(/160.chr/,'').gsub(/194.chr/,'')
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: You should check if the encoding of a page corresponds to the one of your strings. Which Ruby version you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (2018): This code does not work in current Ruby versions. Please refer to other answers.**

You can also try

```
s.gsub(/\xA0|\xC2/, '')
```

or

```
s.delete 160.chr+194.chr
```

Comment: This: ```s.gsub(/\xA0|\xC2/, '')``` is not correct. You need firstly to escape: ```s.gsub(/\\xA0|\\xC2/, '')``` to avoid the ```SyntaxError: (pry):6: invalid multibyte escape: /\xA0|\xC2/``` error and even if you do that you get: ```ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8```. Try ```s.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(0xA0.chr,"")``` for the first and change accordingly for the second.

Answer (score 19):

I found this question while trying to strip out invisible characters when "trimming" a string.

`s.strip` did not work for me and I found that the invisible character had the `ord` number  `194`

None of the methods above worked for me but then I found "[Convert non-breaking spaces to spaces in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588942/convert-non-breaking-spaces-to-spaces-in-ruby) " question which says:

> Use `/\u00a0/` to match non-breaking spaces: `s.gsub(/\u00a0/, ' ')` converts all non-breaking spaces to regular spaces
>
> Use `/[[:space:]]/` to match all whitespace, including Unicode whitespace like non-breaking spaces. This is unlike `/\s/`, which matches only ASCII whitespace.

So glad I found that! Now I'm using:

```
s.gsub(/[[:space:]]/,'')
```

This doesn't answer the question of how to `gsub` specific character codes, but if you're just trying to remove whitespace it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me, as of Ruby 2.1.0. Have an upvote! `s.gsub(/^[:space:]+$/,'')` worked better for my purposes though.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that you want to do a method call but instead you're creating a Regexp. You're searching and replacing strings consisting of the string "160" followed by any character and then the string "chr", and then doing the same except with "160" replaced with "194".

Instead, do `gsub(160.chr, '')`.

Comment: I get the following error if I use that code:

RegexpError: premature end of regular expression: /�/

Comment: I think this is because gsub(194.chr, '') refers to a non ASCII character.

Comment: @dagda1: What Ruby version are you using? I don't get that error in 1.8.7 or 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

First thought would be should you be using gsub! instead of gsub

gsub returns a string and gsub! performs the substitution in place

Comment: I wouldn't say he *should* be using `gsub!`. Without knowing the context, it might be more appropriate or it might be wildly inappropriate.

Comment: I would agree.  I was thinking in this context he wasn't assigning it another variable.  But your right should was the wrong wording.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "invalid multibyte escape" error while trying the above solution, but for a different situation. Google was return \xA0 when the number is greater than 999 and I wanted to remove it. So what I did was use return_value.gsub(/[\xA0]/n,"") instead and it worked perfectly fine for me.