# Ruby removing whitespace?

Tags: ruby

Having some issues removing `&nbsp;` whitespace.

```
vehicle = [" 2013 ", "BMW ", "535 ", "Sedan 4 Door "] 
v = vehicle[0]
# => " 2013 "

v[-1].ord.chr
# => "\xA0"
```

Failed Attempts:

```
vehicle.map { |d| d.gsub(/\S(\w*)/, '\1') }
# => ["2013", "MW", "35", "edan  oor"] (space gone but so are other characters.)

vehicle.map { |d| d.gsub(/\xA0/, '') }
# => SyntaxError: (irb):340: invalid multibyte escape: /\xA0/

vehicle.map { |d| d.gsub(/#{160.chr}/, '') }
# => Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

Answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913900/ruby-1-9-strip-not-removing-whitespace/4201783) works:

```
vehicle.map { |d| d.gsub("\302\240", ' ').strip }
# => ["2013", "BMW", "535", "Sedan 4 Door"]
```

but it doesn't explain why/how. Can someone explain how and why this works? Or suggest an alternative?

Comment: `\S` means *not* a space (in general, the `\ `-capital-letter character classes mean the *opposite* of the corresponding lower-case character classes). Your original attempt works if you change `\S` to `\s`. Note, however, that the use of `(\w*)` is unnecessary; just use `d.gsub(/\s/, '')`.

Comment: @KyleStrand I tried `.gsub(/\s/, '')` and unfortunalty that doesn't work either. See sample output: `=> [[" 2013 ", "Lincoln ", "MKXAWD ", "Utility4x44Door "], [" 2013 ", "BMW ", "X5 ", "Utility4x44Door "], [" 2013 ", "BMW ", "535 ", "Sedan4Door "]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *should* be probably able to simply use `/[[:space:]]/` to match all whitespace ([unicode or not](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes)).

`\302\240` is just the utf8-encoded nbsp representation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689854/ruby-incorrect-method-behaviour-possible-depending-charset

Comment: Just ask it... as another question :)

Comment: So glad I found this.